# Typescript vs Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript, marionette

I recently discovered Typescript. Coming from an OOP C# background, I find Javascript very difficult to work with and am naturally thrilled about Typescript.

I'm currently using Backbone.Marionette.js in my application to manage future complexity (future because it's still the early stage and not yet that complex).

Now I understand there is still room for Backbone.js to play an important role in my application even if I'm using Typescript, but the more I learn Typescript (and begin to love it), the more I start thinking that its objective in managing complexity in enterprise application overlaps too much with what Marionette tries to accomplish. I understand they do it in two completely different ways but coming from C# I of course prefer the OOP approach instead of yet another JS plugin.

Are my considerations to phase out Marionette out of my application justified or is there less overlap than I think? Keep in mind, I'm new to all 3 Backbone, TypeScript, and Marionette and this is the first application I've used them in, which makes it difficult for me to assess this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer would be based on the following considerations.

Firstly, what parts of Marionette are you using? If it is just the module loading then you don't need it. If you are using a lot of the templating and eventing it may be useful still. If you aren't sure yet what parts you might use, don't use it until you have a compelling reason to use it.

Secondly, how much can you write before you need to make decision? For example, if you start coding today, how long can you defer the decision. The longer you wait, the more information you'll have to help you make the right choice. If you write plain TypeScript, you can wait until you actually need to bring in a framework or toolkit and then choose the one that solves your real problem.

So really, my answer is start without it and wait until you have a problem to solve before choosing how you solve it.

Answer (score 5):

"TypeScript vs Marionette" is the wrong perspective. That would be like "C# vs WinForms", and asking "Should I stop using WinForms when I switch from C# to VB.NET?" This question doesn't make any sense because it is trying to compare a language to a framework.

There are some things that [TypeScript will prevent you from doing with Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075487/how-do-i-tell-typescript-about-dynamic-addition-of-properties) or any other JavaScript framework that takes advantage of JavaScript being dynamic. But that doesn't mean TypeScript replaces Marionette or any other framework. It only limits the usefulness of the framework due to restrictions that TypeScript places on you.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't limit you from using dynamic properties. Use bracket notation or define your objects to be type `any`. If you still want compile time checking extend the definition via interfaces, etc.